# Cakephp : how can i retrieve my media files from the folder to display on my view page

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. what i have done right now is ..  i am displaying a user a form in which i have given him the option to upload an audio file .. so i have taken the file from the user .. i am saving the file into the app/uploads folder .. and the path into the database ... now the problem is i dont how can i know retrieve my audio file and show them into my view page

here is my uploading function

```
 public function audio(){


    if ($this->request->isPost()){
        $this->loadModel('Audio');
        $file = $this->request->data['Audio']['file'];

         $idUser = $this->Auth->user('idUser');


        if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $id = String::uuid();
            $name =$file['name'];

            $folder_url = APP.'uploads/'.$idUser;
        if(!is_dir($folder_url)) {
            mkdir($folder_url);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],  $folder_url.DS.$name);

            $this->request->data['Audio']['User_id'] = $idUser;
            $this->request->data['Audio']['filename'] = $file['name'];
            $this->request->data['Audio']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
            $this->request->data['Audio']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
            $this->Audio->save($this->request->data);


            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }

 public function showAllAudioFiles(){
   }
```

now the file of particular user has stored into this folder **app/uploads/23/file.mp3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

Assuming you only have one file per user, you jsut need to find the database record and construct the path from that:

```
public function showAllAudioFiles(){
    $record = $this->Audio->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User_id' => $this->Auth->user('idUser')));
    $file = APP . 'uploads' . DS . $this->Auth->user('idUser') . DS . $record['Audio']['filename'] . '.' . $record['Audio']['filemime'];
    $this->set('file', $file);
}
```

If a user can have multiple files:

```
public function showAllAudioFiles(){
    $records = $this->Audio->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User_id' => $this->Auth->user('idUser')));
    $files = array();
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $files[] = APP . 'uploads' . DS . $this->Auth->user('idUser') . DS . $record['Audio']['filename'] . '.' . $record['Audio']['filemime'];
    }
    $this->set('files', $files);
}
```

Now the `$file` variable will contain a string of the format **app/uploads/23/file.mp3**, for example. Or `$files` will be an array of those strings.

### Suggestion:

Doing it the proper 'Cake' way, you would just retrieve the records and echo them using the `media` method of `HtmlHelper`:

ACTION:

```
public function showAllAudioFiles(){
        $record = $this->Audio->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User_id' => $this->Auth->user('idUser')));
        $this->set('file', $record);
}
```

VIEW:

```
echo $this->Html->media($file['Audio']['filename'] . '.' . $file['Audio']['filemime'],
    array('pathPrefix' => 'uploads' . DS . $file['Audio']['User_id']
);
```

This should output something like this:

```
 <audio src="/uploads/23/file.mp3"></audio>
```

### Creating a link to the file

Edit: For links to files, just use HtmlHelper's `link` method:

```
 echo $this->Html->link($file['Audio']['filename'], WWW_ROOT . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $file['Audio']['User_id'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filename'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filemime']);
```

[HtmlHelper::media](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3amedia)

Comment: thankyou for your answer ... i exactly paste your code i have add this line $this->set('path',$path); and when i echo it on my view page it displays the path not the file .. i want to display the file so user can download it

Comment: Hi, I just added how to do that to the bottom of my answer - hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: sir thank you for your help ... i think i am very close now ... i have tried your first answer .. which is before the "doing it to the proper Cake way" one which is for single files ... and then on my view page i   paste your last code "Creating a link to the file".. but it is giving me the errors that Auth Helper could not be found ... and when i tryed your cake proper way code .. the same error comes up.. sorry for the problem

Comment: Hi there, that's a different problem altogether - you need to make sure you're including 'Auth' in the `$helpers` array of your controller. Or in the view, try `AuthComponent::user('idUser')` instead of `$this->Auth->user('idUser')`. I think that should work :)

Comment: Or instead of using Auth in the view at all, just use `$file['Audio']['User_id']`, which is probably a better way of doing it anyway seeing as you've already retrieved that data. I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: sir every thing is just fine .. now the path error is coming .. as when i click the url what it does is it is going to this url localhost/cakephp/media/C:/xampp/htdocs/cakephp/app/uploads/231011029_10152615392142588_1926259269_n.jpg            ....

Comment: Try this: `echo $this->Html->link($file['Audio']['filename'], WWW_ROOT . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $file['Audio']['User_id'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filename'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filemime'], array('full_base' => true));`. It should create an absolute URL instead.

Comment: now the link is redirecting to this ...https://localhost/cakephp/media/C:/xampp/htdocs/cakephp/app/webroot//uploads/23/1011029_10152615392142588_1926259269_n.jpg/image/jpeg                      and i want to mention that my file is not in webroot folder .. it is in app/uploads/23,  23 is user id

Comment: Ok, I see. Then try: `$this->Html->link($file['Audio']['filename'], APP_PATH . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $file['Audio']['User_id'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filename'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filemime'], array('full_base' => true));`. Hopefully it works now, if not we should move this discussion to chat and get it working. Maybe you can try to figure it out yourself too.

Comment: yeah definitely if you run out ov ur solutions i will try then myself.. the error is comming again this   Use of undefined constant APP_PATH - assumed 'APP_PATH'  and after clicking the link https://localhost/cakephp/media/APP_PATH/uploads/23/1011029_10152615392142588_1926259269_n.jpg/image/jpeg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33654/discussion-between-mynameisjohn-and-sharkofmirkwood)